# USB to VGA driver for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, usb, graphics, video

I recently purchased [this](http://www.malloom.com/usb-3-0-to-vga-video-display-external-cable-adapter-for-win-7-8-white) product for my laptop. I couldn't find any supported linux drivers for it. So should I return it or is there a solution for this?

`lsusb` command outputs this:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:3121 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:5775 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HP "Truevision HD" laptop camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1d5c:2000  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1d5c:2000 disappers if I unplug the adapter.

PS: I don't have a CD-ROM drive in my laptop so I couldn't check CD contents that comes within.

Comment: As far as I know it is not supported by Linux.

Comment: It may be supported by the Displaylink drivers: http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu

Comment: Reading your link the $15 product clearly states it works with Win 7/8. However from the same store a $30 product works with Linux and does a lot more: [usb-dvi-vga-hdmi](http://www.malloom.com/usb-dvi-vga-hdmi-adapter-splitter-connect-extra-crt-lcd-projector). Another good question would be to ask how to replace "" (blanks) in lsusb with "USB to VGA Adapter" or something else more descriptive.

Comment: Yes, I think I should return this product immediately. Case closed. I'll buy another product then.